# python, mysql, inserting string into table, error 1054

Tags: python, mysql, string, insert, mysql-error-1054

I am having the problem
OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'Ellie' in 'field list'")
With the code below, I'm trying to insert data from  json into a my sql database. The problem happens whenever I try to insert a string in this case "Ellie" This is something do to with string interpolation I think but I cant get it to work despite trying some other solutions I have seen here..

CREATE TABLE

```
con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','','tweetsdb01')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User(user_id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, username varchar(25) NOT NULL,user varchar(25) NOT NULL) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB")
con.commit()
```

INSERT INTO

```
def populate_user(a,b,c):
    con = MySQLdb.connect('localhost','root','','tweetsdb01')
    cursor = con.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User(user_id,username,user) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"%(a,b,c))
    con.commit() 
    cursor.close()
```

READ FILE- this calls the populate method above

```
def read(file):
    json_data=open(file)
    tweets = []
    for i in range(10):
        tweet = json.loads(json_data.readline())

    populate_user(tweet['from_user_id'],tweet['from_user_name'],tweet['from_user'])
```

Comment: if it is the cursor, during open error means. In the cursor select statement where clause it is expecting numeric value, but you passed character value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use parametrized SQL](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User(user_id,username,user) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)", (a,b,c))
```

(Notice the values `(a,b,c)` are passed to the function `execute` as a second argument, not as part of the first argument through string interpolation). MySQLdb will properly quote the arguments for you.

---

PS. As Vajk Hermecz notes, the problem occurs because the string `'Ellie'` is not being properly quoted.

When you do the string interpolation with `"(%s,)" % (a,)` you get 
`(Ellie,)` whereas what you really want is `('Ellie',)`. But don't bother doing the quoting yourself. It is safer and easier to use parametrized SQL.

Comment: ok, Thanks! I was also having a utf encoding problem.. I think both issues in this new domain for me, at the same time was making me crazy!!

Comment: What if I have int, date and other types in my mysql? %s will do just fine?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are adding the values into the query without any escaping.... Now it is just broken. You could do something like:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User(user_id,username,user) VALUES(\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")"%(a,b,c))
```

But that would just introduce SQL INJECTION into your code.

NEVER construct SQL statements with concatenating query and data. Your parametrized queries...

The proper solution here would be:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO User(user_id,username,user) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)", (a,b,c))
```

So, the problem with your code was that you have used the `%` operator which does string formatting, and finally you just gave one parameter to `cursor.execute`. Now the proper solution, is that instead of doing the string formatting yourself, you give the query part to `cursor.execute` in the first parameter, and provide the tuple with arguments in the second parameter.